# Add a new column with group sum (DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with duplicate names and payments, I want to add a third column with salary (all payments = salary) with grouping by people. I need to add a column to an existing table in DAX (pbi). Can you help with the code?

```
Name    Payments    Salary
Peter   5000        9300
Ivan    2500        7600
John    3100        6500
Peter   4300        9300
William 4250        6850
Michael 1900        6500
John    3400        6500
Michael 4600        6500
Mike    6700        6700
William 2600        6850
Ivan    5100        7600
```

But now I only have this formula, which does not work and gives the error :

> The expression references more than one column. Multiple columns
> cannot be converted to a scalar value.

```
Salary = SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[name], "Salary", SUM('Table'[refs]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the `SUMMARIZE` function in your formula is that it actually returns a table and not a single scalar value, which is what you're expecting in a calculated column.

Instead, you should use the `SUMX` and `FILTER` functions :

```
Salary = 
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        'Table',
        'Table'[Name] = EARLIER('Table'[Name])
    ),
    'Table'[Payments]
)
```

[image]